# How to fix raise SysCallError(errno, errorcode.get(errno)) OpenSSL.SSL.SysCallError: (10054, 'WSAECONNRESET') in netlify api?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, curl, netlify

I am trying to perform a post through a curl in python.
Basically it's [Netlify API](https://docs.netlify.com/api/get-started/#zip-file-method) to perform manual deploys of website programmticallly
Now when i run my below code I get following errors `raise SysCallError(errno, errorcode.get(errno))
OpenSSL.SSL.SysCallError: (10054, 'WSAECONNRESET')` . Then other bunch of 
 I don't know what's causing the issue, any help is highly appreciated 
thanks

here is the code

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/zip',
    'Authorization': 'df75a872267756dcc################',#hiding for security reasons
 }

data = open('PathOr Personal wesite.zip', 'rb').read()
response = requests.post('https://api.netlify.com/api/v1/sites/www.pathor.ml/deploys', 
headers=headers, data=data)
print(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

It means you are getting a RST when doing the TCP handshake. Common reasons are firewalls or nothing listening on that port.

Comment: Thanks for your answer first! So what should be the possible solution , as I'm completely newbie.

Comment: Run, from the host where your script runs:
curl -k https://api.netlify.com/api/v1/sites/www.pathor.ml/deploys
This should be your first step.